# Skip one frame (with JS code) in Shiny App (R) video on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, r, google-chrome, shiny

I've written a Shiny application that displays a video and has a button to skip to the next frame. It works when running it in Firefox and Edge but it fails in Chrome. Instead of moving to the next frame the video jumps back to the start.

After internet research it seemed to be an issue with Chrome that I thought couldn't be helped, however I've found a website where the functionality does work in Chrome and I can't figure out what the difference is that makes my code fail.

Here is the Shiny app: (Note that I use a video called 'test_vid.MP4' that has 29 frames per second and is stored in the App's 'www' folder.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Javascript code to go to a specific time
jsCode <- "shinyjs.vid0 = function(value){
  var vid=document.getElementById('v0');
  vid.pause();
  vid.currentTime=value;}"

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$nxt, {
    js$vid0(input$vid0_currentTime + 1 / 29) # My video is 29 frames per second
  })
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("nxt", "Next frame")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Update input$vid0_currentTime
      tags$script("
          document.getElementById('nxt').onclick = function() {
            var myVid = document.getElementById('v0');
            Shiny.onInputChange('vid0_currentTime', myVid.currentTime);
          };
        "),
      # Video output in HTML
      HTML(paste('<center><video id="v0" controls tabindex="0" height = "600px">',
                 '<source type="video/mp4" ',
                 paste0('src="test_vid.MP4">'),
                 '</source></center>'))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I run:

- R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
- Shiny version: shiny_1.0.4
- shinyjs version: shinyjs_0.9.1
- Chrome Versie 60.0.3112.101 (Officiële build) (64-bits)
- Firefox 54.0.1 (64-bit)
- Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0

The website where frame skipping does work with a Chrome browser is http://inconduit.com/smpte/ and the code that does it can be found in the seekFrames function in view-source:http://inconduit.com/smpte/js/smpte_test_universal.js. I believe I use the same functionality so I'm not sure why that works and mine fails.

FYI I don't know much about Javascript.

Thanks!
Jiddu Alexander